# Yii syntax error on autoload_real.php , hosted in Azure as Webapp

Tags: azure, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, azure-webapps

I have a Yii2 advanced application , which is hosted in azure as webapp.
I am facing some issues recently. What I am getting is,

`PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '(' in D:\home\site\wwwroot\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 67`

Problem is, it is occuring some times only. After few minutes, it will go away. Or it will go away, after restarting the webapp. Can anyone help me on this? I am not sure about exact issue, whether it is server side or application side !

Comment: What is in `vendor\composer\autoload_real.php` on line 67? And why on Earth you're using Windows to host PHP app?

Comment: Its an already existing application. The one who did the project earlier was hosted in Windows.  
This is what in line 67,
function composerRequire684fec1a26088e557c7bd0b4a4329946($fileIdentifier, $file)

Thing is it will work after restart :(

Comment: There is no `:` in that line.

Comment: no, There isnt any. I have checked